# Why was my question about complex exponentiation closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked [a question about a generic form of complex exponentiation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748210/what-is-the-generic-formula-for-complex-exponentiation), and it got closed on the grounds that "I need more context". I'm happy to oblige, but I don't know exactly what I need to improve. Does the exact use case I need complex exponentiation for need to be included? (I'm trying to implement a fully featured complex number class in a code library.) Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was not deleted.  It was closed.  Have you checked the links given in the close banner? e.g. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/ ?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Ooops! Sorry, I meant closed. I'll fix that. But yes, I have, and I still am not sure what I need to fix

Comment: You should know some of the theory of complex analysis in order to understand why there is no well defined value for (say) $i^i$.  This is the subject of many earlier posts on Math.SE, so you need to be more forthcoming about what motivates your Question.

Comment: @hardmath Ah, I'm still pretty new to advanced math with complex numbers, and I didn't understand that. If I edited mentioning that I'm trying to implement exponents for complex numbers in code, would that help?

Comment: It might help.  Essentially (as the Comments left on your Question try to convey) some domain restrictions are needed to make the operation of complex exponentiation well-defined (single-valued).  What restrictions one wants naturally depend on the purpose of your code library.

Comment: OP has deleted the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, even after updating it it was still closed for some reason? I just gave up honestly

Comment: So happy the moderators are back off strike! /s

Comment: @BradyGilg ? wdym

Answer (score 3):

The closure reason was to "provide additional context". Admittedly, that is not terribly explanatory; however, if one follows the link to [provide additional context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), several methods of adding context are given. It is hard to answer a question when the level of the asker is not known. Context can help there.

Although not used as a reason to close this question, a question can be closed for being a duplicate. This question may have (partial) answers elsewhere as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I had read that and was still confused, so I asked here. I searched the site but could not find an answer to my question, other than the fact that it may have multiple answers? And something about needing a logarithm defined first.

Comment: The answers to [Complex power of a complex number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/476968) (which was mentioned in a comment) seem to be useful.

Comment: As for the addition of context, some of the suggestions were 1. **Include your work**: you mentioned you know how to raise a complex number to the power $i$. You could include that. Doing that gets you most of the way there. 2. **You can tell us where the question comes from**: the course or the book would give a clue to the level of answer needed. 3. **Give definitions**: this can be useful in many cases; in this case, the definition of the complex log and the complex exponential might prove useful.